# Trying to figure out how to make second call

Tags: angular

I have an *Angular* control where I'm making a call to one function from an API end point. I'm trying to figure out how I can then take the result of that call and use a value from that inside a followup call.

So for example, I make a call for user information. When that get's returned, I want to make a second API call using the user's age, or height...

So I'm calling it within `@OnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.memberInfo()
        .subscribe(res =>{
            this.user = res.json();
    })
}
```

In AngularJS we had the `.then()` function that we would use for a followup action after the first process completed.

How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you call that method inside  subscribe()?

Comment: Yup. That worked. Silly thing to get stuck on. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you accepted my comment as a correct answer, I am creatin this answer so others also can refer

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.memberInfo()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.user = res.json();
        this.getDetails(this.user.age);
      })
  }

  getDetails(age : number){
       this.auth.WhateverTheMethod().subscribe(result => {
        // result
        })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing you from doing another API call inside the first subscribe method..

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.auth.memberInfo()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.user = res.json();
        // example API call
        this.http.get(`/api/user/age/{this.user.age}`).subscribe(result => {
        // do what you need to do with result here
        })
      })
  }
```